# HTTP Request header issue in Android

Tags: android, rest, http-headers

I am trying to fire an API in which I need to add two headers i.e token and deviceid. Below is my code to add header:

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(nameValuePairs[0].get(0).getValue().toString());
        nameValuePairs[0].remove(0);

        ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

        // set header

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setHeader("deviceid", "358978060711939");
        httpPost.setHeader("token", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJHVUlEIjoiYjdlNjZiOWQtMjBjNy00MGI2LTliMzgtOTc3OGQ2OWIwM2E1IiwiRU5USVRZIjoiRUFCTSIsIlVOSVQiOiJVQk0yIiwiUk9MRU5BTUUiOiJTRUxGIiwiSUQiOiIwMDAyMzciLCJBTFRJRCI6IjMzMyIsIlVTRVJfTkFNRSI6IkFuaWwiLCJMT0dJTl9HVUlEX0tFWSI6ImU2NWM2YWEzLTZlNDItNDUyYS1hOGEwLWRlYzRhMGRiNTIxNyIsImlhdCI6MTQ1OTI0ODkyM30.m742d9xd6XlBBjZ3_ODWuoCEdWvSkhPAuNrDee1vi74");

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs[0]));
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, res);
```

In Response I am getting: **org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found**

When I replace token with any alpha numeric value then I am getting response with error message. But when I passed actual token value which is mentioned above I am getting exception. Even I tried with addHeader function also but getting same issue. I am unable to understand how to resolve this error.

Comment: consult your web service developer regarding this

Comment: before consulting I want to make sure my code is correct or not. Mistake should not be at my end.

Comment: not found seems to come in case when either device id or token is invalid

Comment: Try to debug it with wireshark. There you can see the entire http message you send. If you send the correct header, try to contact the web service developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the handler which is causing the error. Don't use.
**You should either write your own handler or call execute without a handler.**

```
 httpClient.execute(httpPost);//remove the handler
```

I hope this is helpful. ThankYou

Comment: Thank You ... It works 
Can I get explanation of this for my knowledge why removing the handler It worked?

Comment: sure! before that can i know what response you are getting from the server

Comment: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:76)

This was error which I was getting from server before trying your logic.
After that I got proper response in JSON format

Comment: BasicResponseHandler are only used to StringResponse,  its done this way                                              HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
  String  responseBody = responsehandler.handleResponse(response);                and it is also said not to use BasicResponseHandler in real time. if you ask me you should stop using apache httpclient. it's decripted. please use volley. it's better and faster then all. ThankYou

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html

Comment: check this out. i did try and do some research there's not much about ResponseHandler's on web

Comment: anytime! you can always contact me here joissumanth@gmail.com ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

Your token seems to be incorrect. Header set in HTTP protocols has their own restrictions. To check it, just try to send your trim token (ex 30 chars).

If it don't helped, you have incorrect another parameters. Anyway, i would give you advice, to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).